# AngularJS - Unit Test - Controller not defined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

My controller definition is as follows:

```
angular.module("rmt.account-info").controller('AccountInfoController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$modal', 'AccountInfoServices', 'UserServices', 'Profile',
function ($scope, $rootScope, $modal, AccountInfoServices, UserServices, Profile) {
```

and I am trying to write Unit Test for this controller as follows:

```
describe("Account Info Module", function(){
describe("Account Info Controller", function(){
    var scope, ctrl;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module("rmt.account-info");

        var accountInfoMockService = {}, userMockService = {}, mockedProfileFactory = {};
        var fakeModal = 
        {   
            result: {
                then: function(confirmCallback, cancelCallback){
                    this.confirmCallback = confirmCallback;
                    this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
                }
            },
            close: function(item){
                this.result.confirmCallback(item);  
            },
            dismiss: function(reason){
                this.result.cancelCallback(reason);
            }
        };

        module(function($provide, $modal){
            $provide.value('AccountInfoServices', accountInfoMockService);
            $provide.value('UserServices', userMockService);
            $provide.value('Profile', mockedProfileFactory);

            spyOn($modal, 'open').and.returnValue(fakeModal);

            return null;
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$modal_, _AccountInfoServices_, _UserServices_, _Profile_){
        scope = _$rootScope_.new();
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $modal = _$modal_;
        AccountInfoServices = _AccountInfoServices_;
        UserServices = _UserServices_;
        Profile = _Profile_;
        ctrl = _$controller_("accountInfoController", {
            $scope              : scope,
            $rootScope          : $rootScope,
            $modal              : $modal,
            AccountInfoServices : AccountInfoServices,
            UserServices        : UserServices,
            Profile             : Profile
        });
    }));

    describe("Initial State", function(){
        it("should instantiate the controller properly", function(){
            expect(ctrl).not.toBeUndefined();
        });
    });

});

describe("Account Info Service", function(){

});
});
```

Please help to know where I am going wrong, I get the following error in my terminal:

**Failed to instantiate module {0} due to:
{1}**

Using Karma as Test Runner and Jasmine - testing framework

[Console log error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=rmt.account-info&p1=%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.15%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0AR%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fc8470371db8d3735604343a9a059002d3a827663:6:417%0Aab%2Fp.$injector%3C@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fc8470371db8d3735604343a9a059002d3a827663:38:7%0Ad@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fc8470371db8d3735604343a9a059002d3a827663:36:13%0Ae@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fc8470371db8d3735604343a9a059002d3a827663:36:283%0Ad@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fc8470371db8d3735604343a9a059002d3a827663:34:490%0Ag%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fc8470371db8d3735604343a9a059002d3a827663:35:117%0Ar@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fc8470371db8d3735604343a9a059002d3a827663:7:300%0Ag@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fc8470371db8d3735604343a9a059002d3a827663:34:399%0Aab@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fc8470371db8d3735604343a9a059002d3a827663:38:135%0AworkFn@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular-mocks%2Fangular-mocks.js%3F22d2ba1b1057c6b4d908b5bef8c0f16e46f8b036:2353:44%0AattemptSync@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1789:9%0AQueueRunner.prototype.run@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1777:9%0AQueueRunner.prototype.execute@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1762:5%0AEnv%2FqueueRunnerFactory@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:627:7%0ASpec.prototype.execute@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:353:1%0AexecuteNode%2F%3C.fn@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:2361:32%0AattemptAsync@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1819:9%0AQueueRunner.prototype.run@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1774:9%0AQueueRunner.prototype.execute@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1762:5%0AEnv%2FqueueRunnerFactory@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:627:7%0AexecuteNode%2F%3C.fn@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:2346:1%0AattemptAsync@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1819:9%0AQueueRunner.prototype.run@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1774:9%0AQueueRunner.prototype.execute@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1762:5%0AEnv%2FqueueRunnerFactory@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:627:7%0AexecuteNode%2F%3C.fn@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:2346:1%0AattemptAsync@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1819:9%0AQueueRunner.prototype.run@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1774:9%0AQueueRunner.prototype.execute@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1762:5%0AEnv%2FqueueRunnerFactory@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:627:7%0AexecuteNode%2F%3C.fn@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:2346:1%0AattemptAsync@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1819:9%0AQueueRunner.prototype.run@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1774:9%0AQueueRunner.prototype.execute@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:1762:5%0AEnv%2FqueueRunnerFactory@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:627:7%0ATreeProcessor%2Fthis.execute@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:2209:1%0AEnv%2Fthis.execute@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3841e315a3de20765ab2a6b7965198f3aaf2f594:678:7%0AcreateStartFn%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fadapter.js%3F0a69ad1fa10cc8be0a12b241227d3b834f82db4f:317:5%0A%5B2%5D%3C%2FKarma%2Fthis.loaded@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fkarma.js:185:7%0A@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9018%2Fcontext.html:509:5%0A)

Comment: your controller is 'AccountInfoController' not 'accountInfoController', with capital 'A'

Comment: Good notice... ! but this didn't help. The error I get in console - mentions about "routeProvide". Too long to copy here

Comment: Paste it in a pastebin or a git gist and leave the link then. The error message is what helps to solve the issue

Comment: I have edited the answer for the same. "Console log error" .It is the link to angular docs and it gives  Failed to instantiate module {0} due to: {1}. Link itself has words like "routeProvider" or so

Comment: It sounds like you've not setup your dependencies, probably not included angular.route.js in your js files that are loaded by your tests.

Comment: I do include "angular.route.js".

Comment: Without a running example or the error message you're on your own.

Comment: @BenCr I didn't understand what you trying to say?

Comment: You're not including enough detail in your question for someone to be able to answer. You should either provide more info or even better create a running example on something like jsFiddle.

Comment: Can you explain what else is required to understand the scenario and problem? Till then I just work out to create a jsFiddle for it.. Actually, I am new to Unit Testing, so just can't understand what is missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78808/discussion-between-yashika-garg-and-bencr).